# Py_RunString Returns Only None Object

Tags: python, c++

I'm using Python 3.4.3 embded in my c++ project, When I Call Py_RunString it always returns None object.
here is my code

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <string>
int main(){
    //Initialize the python interpreter
    Py_Initialize(); 
    //create new dictionary containing both global and local definitions
    PyObject *globals = PyDict_New();
    PyObject *locals = PyDict_New(); 

    //Set the build in definitions to the global dictionary: eg:len, str ,.. funtions
    PyDict_SetItemString(globals, "__builtins__", PyEval_GetBuiltins());
    //evaluate some python code and get the result, here is my issue, always None 
    PyObject *string_result = PyRun_StringFlags(
        "1 + 1" /*or what ever python code*/
        ,
        Py_file_input, globals, locals, NULL);
    //check whether the python code caused any Exception and print it
    if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
        PyErr_Print(); PyErr_Clear(); return 1;
    }
    else {
    //if no Exceptions then try To Get string represiation of the python object, But it always None
        auto str = PyToStr(string_result);
        printf("python result is %s",str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and here is my Function that convert any python object to c++ std::wstring

```
std::wstring PyToStr(PyObject*  Object)
{
    //it is equivalent to python code : str(Object)
    PyObject* objectsRepresentation = PyObject_Str(Object);
    //convert Python String Object to C++ wchar_t*
    const wchar_t* ws = PyUnicode_AsUnicode(objectsRepresentation);

    if (ws)
        return ws;
    //if ws is NULL it could not be converted implicitly to std::wstring
    return L"";
}
```

Comment: Does it return ``None`` or ``NULL``?

Comment: if the python code succeeded with no Exceptions it returns None object, otherwise 'PyRun_StringFlags' returns NULL

Comment: It might be me, but I'd suggest you edit the code with comments to clarify this stuff. How did ``PyErr_Occurred()`` evaluate? looking at the question, it's hard to understand what you're asking exactly (again, it might be me).

Comment: the upove code is OK, If the python code passed to `PyRun_StringFlags` contains any `print statment`, it executed successfully, but what I really need is to **evaluate some python expressions** and get the value from it, but it always return **None**

Comment: about the comments, Ok I will edit the Question

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to evaluate a single line you can use Py_eval_input instead of Py_file_input. It should then return the evaluated value.